# ArcGIS javascript API Printing: fuzzy result

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, printing

I created a real simple web app, copied from samples actually, to try figuring out something about the Print Dijit.
Here's the thing. When you click print [here](http://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/wp-content/themes/topografieindeklas/playground_topourl.php) there are two major concers with the result:

1. The symbology, especially the rectangle in the bottom left corner, are mashed up.
2. The background layer is not that high quality as it is in the browser

Any thoughts how this is possible and how to resolve both issues?

Answer (score 2):

try setting the preserveScale property of the PrintTemplate to true.  this should ensure that the actual reference scale of the basemap is printed, otherwise resampling is necessary to attempt to display the same extent.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/printtemplate-amd.html#preservescale

Comment: Did not do the job unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you are printing the background as a tiled layer.  Take a look at this document from ESRI about high quality printing. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000056t000000

Update: I've recently run into this same issue myself.  In my case its because of the tiled layer, in order for the print out to not have a fuzzy appearance, it may be necessary to set the scale of the print to the nearest tile cached scale.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Whoever, the problem seems to resident in the symbols. When using default symbols from the Esri documentation, the fuzziness will disappear. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Can you show me one of the symbols?

Comment: The symbols are on http://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/wp-content/themes/topografieindeklas/playground_topourl.php. As in this web map: http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=0990882a42d2493f83894286a16f347e

Comment: Looks like you are using a byte string instead of an url to an image...have you tried using an image url? https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_nederland/FeatureServer/0?f=pjson

Comment: Yes I did actually, no luck either.